# references sites and page web

Tags: bibliographies, urls, apacite

can anyone tell me how to fix this reference I get this result:

```
   Fletcher, T. (2009). Support vector machines explained.
```

while I have to get like in the figue below. I am using bibtex any help!
I cite it like this `\cite{fletcher2009support}`. I am using `\bibliographystyle{apacite}` I have url and hyperref

[image: here is what I have to get]

same problem for this page `https://www.quora.com/What-are-Kernels-in-Machine-Learning-and-SVM`

how please to fix this

```
@misc{fletcher2009support,
      title={Support vector machines explained},
      author={Fletcher, Tristan},
      journal={University College London, London},
      year={2009},
      howpublished = "{\url{http://sutikno.blog.undip.ac.id/files/2011/11/SVM-      Explained.pdf}",
      note = {Accessed: 2017-04-30}
       }
```

Comment: You can load the `url` package for improve the URL insertion... you don't need the quotes, and strictly, the URL does not go in the field of `howpublished`. Why don't you try with `electronic` or `online`?

Comment: I have deleted the "" but still not working please can you give me an example with `electronic` by the way I have url package already but it does not give me the result

Comment: I have tried instead of  `howpublished`` online` and  `electronic` all the time same result :| does display the url nor the acceded  note

Comment: Well, you shoudl give us an MWE (Minimal Working Example) that we can read for understand your problem. Sorry for the confusion, I was reading about how bibtex works and by default there is not support for web pages, I'm sorry, there is a long time I don't use bibtex, I preffer to use biblatex.

Comment: @Aradnix - The `apacite` bibliography style does not provide for fields called `electronic` or `online`. Better to use `url` as the field name -- or just keep using `howpublished` and fix the typos.

Comment: You've probably noticed that the contents of the `journal` field aren't shown either. That's because the `journal` field is always ignored *unless* it occurs in an entries of type `@article`, `@phdthesis`, or `@mastersthesis`. Anyway, for the entry at hand, the field `journal={University College London, London},` would seem quite incorrect; just as well that its contents aren't shown!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have two [2!] errors just in the `url` field. Instead of

```
howpublished = "{\url{http://sutikno.blog.undip.ac.id/files/2011/11/SVM-      Explained.pdf}",
```

it should be either

```
howpublished = "\url{http://sutikno.blog.undip.ac.id/files/2011/11/SVM-Explained.pdf}",
```

or

```
howpublished = {\url{http://sutikno.blog.undip.ac.id/files/2011/11/SVM-Explained.pdf}},
```

Observe that you must either delete the first instance of `{` or delete the outer pair of double quotes and furnish a closing curly brace.

Alternatively, you could make use of the fact that the `apacite` bibliography style knows about a field called `url` and thus rewrite the field as

```
url = "http://sutikno.blog.undip.ac.id/files/2011/11/SVM-Explained.pdf",
```

The second error: you really must delete the space in the file name as well (unless you wish to make the URL nearly useless to your readers...).

A full MWE:

[image]

```
\RequirePackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{mybib.bib}
@misc{fletcher2009support,
 title  = {Support vector machines explained},
 author = {Fletcher, Tristan},
 journal= {University College London, London},
 year   = {2009},
 howpublished = "\url{http://sutikno.blog.undip.ac.id/files/2011/11/SVM-Explained.pdf}",
 note   = {Accessed: 2017-04-30}
}
\end{filecontents}

\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{apacite}
\bibliographystyle{apacite}
\usepackage[hyphens]{url}

\begin{document}
\cite{fletcher2009support}
\bibliography{mybib}
\end{document}
```

---

*Addendum*: The `apacite` bibliography style knows what to make of fields called `url` and `urldate`, respectively. If you were to change the two fields in question (`howpublished` and `note`) to

```
 url = {http://sutikno.blog.undip.ac.id/files/2011/11/SVM-Explained.pdf},
 urldate= {2017-04-30},
```

and recompile the preceding MWE, you'd get the following output:

[image]

Comment: thank you very much :) it works finally am very gratefull thank you

Comment: please can you tell me if this is correct or not ! I have this page  (https://www.quora.com/What-are-Kernels-in-Machine-Learning-and-SVM) I have tired this  ` @misc{Hariharan,
 title  = {What are Kernels in Machine Learning and SVM?},
 author = {Hariharan, B. (n.d.).},
 howpublished = "\url{https://www.quora.com/What-are-Kernels-in-Machine-Learning-and-SVM}",
 note   = {Accessed: 2017-04-15}
}` i got this it is correct `Hariharan, B. n. (n.d.). What are kernels in machine learning and
svm? https://www.quora.com/What-are-Kernels-in-Machine
-Learning-and-SVM. (Accessed: 2017-04-15)`

Comment: @mirette - Please post a new query. In the new query, please be sure to state what you mean by "correct". (And please use fewer exclamation marks -- or none at all.)